# Fruit that has been mistaken as olive fruit?

Tags: fruit, food-identification

What fruit is this? I can't find it online. Can someone please help me identify it?

[image]

Comment: are you able to cut one in half (cut open) and show the inside?

Answer (score 5):

I took your picture and gave it as input to https://identify.plantnet.org/
, which is an online tool to help identify plants with pictures.
According to PlantNet, your fruit is **most probably a climbing ylang-ylang.**

It is native to southern India and Sri Lanka.
Its flowers smell very fragrant, but the fruits don’t seem to taste good.
[image: Picture from plantnet, depicting fruits of climping ylang-ylang]